# mvc open partial view in jquery dialog pass parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

help please

I have a view with many buttons...each button has unique ID. I want to open a partial view in a jquery dialog box.  I can see the dialog box and even see the partial form in it, but I cannot get a parameter passed to it. 
the following script works...but notice I have hard coded the id in the url.  How do I put a variable in there instead of a hardcoded id number.  Thanks very much

```
<script>
               var ASeatId;  //this code works

               function showPersonDialog(seatId) {
                   ASeatId = seatId;
                   $('#dialog').dialog('open');
               }

               $('#dialog').dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   width: 800,
                   resizable: false,
                   title: 'Edit Guest',
                   modal: true,
                   open: function (event, ui) {
                       var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{seatID=3}))';         
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $(this).dialog("save");
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link   
                return false;
            },
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link   
                return false;
            }
        }
});
           </script>
```

so when I step through controller code

```
  public ActionResult Guest(int? seatId)
    {


        return PartialView("_Guest");
        //return PartialView("_Guest");
    }
```

I can see the number 3

I would like to pass a variable instead based on the button click...this code that follows does NOT work

```
       <script>  ///this code does not work
           var ASeatId;

           function showPersonDialog(seatId) {
               ASeatId = seatId;
               $('#dialog').dialog('open');
           }

           $('#dialog').dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               width: 800,
               resizable: false,
               title: 'Edit Guest',
               modal: true,
               open: function (event, ui) {
                   var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{seatID=ASeatID}))';  ///this being the variable       
        $(this).load(url);
    },
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
            $(this).dialog("save");
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link   
            return false;
        },
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link   
            return false;
        }
    }
 });
       </script>
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{ seatID = "-1"}))';
url = url.replace("-1", ASeatId);
```

Often getting variables into another variable needs a little help.

Sometimes it may be necessary to convert an integer to number when the action controller is expecting a search string.

```
var aid = ASeatId.toString();
var url = '@Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{ seatID = "-1"}))';
url = url.replace("-1", aid);
$(this).load(url)
```

Most times, a simple load call ( as referenced above) on document ready works best for me (passing the model param).

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{ seatID = Model.ASeatId}))');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (in the dialog's open function)

```
 var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{seatID='+ASeatID+'}))';  ///this being the variable
```

variable does not go to string .!

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried your suggestion. Still not working. Getting a bad compile constant value error. CS1012 Too many characters in character literal.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but
`var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Guest", "Seat", new{seatID=eval(ASeatID)'}))';` may be?

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
$("#customerTabBody").load('Home/GetCustomerList', { 'searchString': searchCriteria });
```

Here the searchCriteria is the parameter you have to pass

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried this way and still not working.  Don't get any errors but my partial view does not load at all...I have a code break at my controller and it doesn't even hit the controller...so seems like the .load(url, {'seatId':ASeatId}) doesn't get to the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Guest", "Seat")))
url = url + ASeatId;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Guest", "Seat")" +"/" + ASeatID;
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! generally, code-only answers without explanations are not preferred... would you consider adding some explanation to your answer?